# Difference between "rails new ." and "rails __version__ new myapp" in starting a new rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newbie to Ruby on Rails here. Pretty dumb question I suspect. Are there differences between the two? I'm just bothered by "." These are probably the same command with differences being ____version____ and the "."
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well these are two different things but both are use to create rails application

```
rails new .
```

the Unix “dot” convention to refer to the current directory. This assigns the name of the directory to the new application. if you specify name instead of `'.'` new folder with provided name will be created and rails new application will be created in it.

```
rails _version_ myapp
```

Moving to your second point `rails _version_ myapp` will created new rails application with specified rails version number.

You can merge these two as well `rails _3.1.2_ .` will create rails application with version 3.1.2 and in current directory

Answer (score 1):

Both creates a new rails application. When you are using `rails new myapp` it will create a latest version rails app. If you are using older version of rails you can use `rails_version_new myapp`. More details can be found [here](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.in/2008/06/using-older-versions-of-rails.html?m=1)

And `rails new .` is used to create a rails application in an existing directory. Read official docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)